# What are the advantages for storing simple secrets in KeyVault over Environment variables

Tags: azure, environment-variables, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

I run a very simple nodejs web app on Azure App Services. I need to pass a secret into the app, for which I use `dotenv` locally. I can set these environment variables in Azure configuration `Application settings`. Wonder if the secrets are secure there I found I can also store them in `Key Vault` [referencing](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references) to them in the environment variables using `@Microsoft.KeyVault({referenceString})`. In both places I can "unhide" the secret, so I wonder what the advantage of the one over the other is in my scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Application settings`, the app setting is not really hidden, as you know, simply click `Show values` then you can see it. Also, anyone has the read permission at your web app scope, he will always be able to check this value, not only the portal UI, but also 
azure [`powershell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/?view=azps-3.8.0), [`cli`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/what-is-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest), [`resource explorer`](https://resources.azure.com/), etc.

To store the it as a secret in keyvault is secure, just the one(in your case, the system-assigned identity of the web app) who has the correct permission in the `Access policies` can access the secret. The other people will not be able to access the secret(they are not the RBAC roles e.g. `Owner`, `Contributor` in the subscription/keyvault, otherwise they can add themselves to the `Access policies`).

For more details, see [Secure access to a key vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/secure-your-key-vault).